# haskell function signature

Tags: haskell, signature, type-variables

I'm having a doubt about type signature in haskell. Reading about applicative functor, I have found:

```
pure (+) <*> Just 3
```

which gives back `Just (+3)` which is of type  `Maybe (a->a)`. Now the signature of `<*>` is

```
 (<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which means that our `f b` in the above example is is obtained substituting `f` with `Maybe` and `b` with `a->a`.

And here I was kind of surprised because as far as I knew, `b` cannot unify (sorry if I'm not using specified terminology, but I hope they are clear enough) with `a->a`.

Is that possible just because we are inside and applicative functor or there's something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`b` is a(n unconstrained) type variable, so it can unify with *every* type, always. It has nothing to do with `Applicative` functors, it works wherever a type variable has to be unified with a type.

Roughly, unifying two type expressions results in the most general type expression that is not more general than either partner of the unification. If one of the two type expressions is more general than the other, unification always succeeds and results in the more specific partner of the unification. The most general of all type expressions is one without any structure at all, a type variable. Hence a type variable can be unified with any type expression by instantiating the type variable with that type expression (provided the kinds match, a type variable whose kind is `*` can of course not be unified with the type expression `Maybe` whise kind is `* -> *`).

Comment: So this means that every type signature of a function without constraint, can be of type `a`?

Comment: The other way round. A type variable can be instantiated with every type, that could be a function type, or a list type, or `IO ()`, or... . If the type variable is constrained, only types having an instance for the involved classes are eligible. The result of a unification is always not more general than the unified type expressions. So if you unify a function type with something, the result is a function type, too. A type variable is the most general type expression possible.

Comment: ok, I think I have understood but in that case, why I got Ambiguos error when I do something like 

    `id' :: b`
    `id' = id`

Comment: There your type signature promises that `id'` can have every type, but the implementation provides a less general type, namely `a -> a`. (Though I get ``Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a0 -> a0'`` as the error, not an `Ambiguous type`.) In that situation, the actual inferred type must be at least as general as the type signature specifies, so the result of the unification must [up to renaming of type variables] be exactly the type expression given in the signature.

Comment: Didn't know that, now it's finally clear, tanks :)
Oh and `I got Couldn't match expected type 'b' with actual type 'a0 -> a0' ` as well, my mistake.

Comment: I have been rethinking about this today, and I was wondering why the rule you said apply to this case and not to the example of my question? Since in the example it infers `a -> a` which is less general than `b`

Comment: @user1544128 In your example in the question, you _apply_ `(<*>)`. You can use polymorphic functions at types that are less polymorphic (e.g. `id 'x'` uses `id` at the monomorphic type `Char -> Char`; `id []` uses `id` at the type `[b] -> [b]`, which is polymorphic, but less polymorphic than `a -> a`). But when you define a value, you must define it at least as general as its type promises.

Answer (score 7):

`:t pure (+)` is

```
pure (+) :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f (a -> a -> a)
```

Note the `f(a -> a -> a)`

So since `:t (<*>)` is

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`f ( a -> b)` is actually a `f ( a -> a -> a)`.

So the type variable `b` in this case *is* `a -> a`